# Roblox - Is it possible to start a different dialog than the usual one when the player possesses a specific badge?

Tags: roblox

I want to construct a system where players can talk to a model which has a dialog in it, then they would be required to receive a badge, and when they return to the model, a different dialog would appear (in this case it would congratulate them for earning the badge).

Imagine a player coming up to this model and talking to them. The model would introduce them to the event. When the dialog is finished, the player would earn the badge needed, return to the model, and talk to them again, however this time the model would congratulate them on earning the badge, and would thus have to use a different dialog than the first one. That is what I am trying to achieve.

The initial dialog seems to be working, however the problem is I cannot find a solution to how to change the dialog when the player already has the badge. I am a novice to coding and thus cannot think of anything by myself, too.

I haven't tried anything. As stated, I am a novice in coding. I have also searched the internet for help, however there is nothing that answered my question.

Does anyone know how to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```lua
local badgeId = 00000000 - your Id here
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local ownsBadge = game:GetService("BadgeService"):UserHasBadgeAsync(player.UserId, badgeId)
```

Then see if that's true and if it is, change the Dialogue.
https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BadgeService#UserHasBadgeAsync